# The name of the movie similar to First Men in the Moon

Tags: story-identification, movie

I recall watching a movie very similar to *First Men in the Moon*. But it's made after that film.

In the beginning it's the celebration of the first Moon landing at 1969. A little boy encounters an old man who tells him he and his friend were the first people who landed on the Moon, and all the news of Neil Armstrong being the First Man is a lie.

Then he tells his story. In a flashback he is convinced by a scientist and inventor to go on a journey to the Moon with him. On the Moon they encounter aliens and so on.

The movie ends with the old man finishing his story.

What was the name of the film? Was it also based on the novel the 1964 movie was based on?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There was a remake of The First Men in the Moon in [2010](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1535107/).

> In 1969, the Apollo moon landing is to be televised internationally
> but at a country fair in England a small boy named Jim meets the
> 90-year-old Julius Bedford who tells him that, in 1909, as a
> struggling writer, he met eccentric Professor Cavor, inventor of
> Cavorite, a gravity-defying substance which they used to build a
> sphere, which took them to the Moon. Captured by ant-like Selenites,
> Bedford was anxious to make his escape but Cavor was happy to stay and
> communicate with the Moon-dwellers. Back on Earth, Bedford hears via
> wireless that Cavor was forced to kill himself and the Moon-dwellers
> to prevent them from invading Earth. As Jim watches the Apollo landing
> with his parents, he sees a Selenite, hiding behind a lunar rock,
> peering at the astronauts.

YouTube has a [trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vXhMl8ogMLc).